# Create a JSON by joining dataframes (parent & child)

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a json out of 2 dataframes (one is Parent and the other is child). Child records should be an array forming a nested JSON

**Df1 (Department):**

```
+----------+------------+
| dept_Id  | dept_name  |
+----------+------------+
| 10       | Sales      |
+----------+------------+
```

**Df2 (Employee):**

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| dept_Id  | emp_id | emp_name |
+----------+--------+----------+
| 10       | 1001   | John     |
| 10       | 1002   | Rich     |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

I want the JSON to be created as follows:

```
{
 "dept_id":"10",
 "dept_name":"Sales",
 "employee":[ 
        { "emp_id":"1001","emp_name":"John" },
        { "emp_id":"1002","emp_name":"Rich" }
   ]
}
```

Appreciate your thoughts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join the two dataframes together:

```
val df = df1.join(df2, Seq("dept_Id"))
```

Then use `groupBy` and `collect_list`. Two case classes is used here to get the correct names in the final json. These should be placed outside of the main method.

```
case class Department(dept_Id: Int, dept_name: String, employee: Seq[Employee])
case class Employee(emp_id: Int, emp_name: String)

val dfDept = df.groupBy("dept_id", "dept_name")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"emp_id", $"emp_name")).as("employee"))
  .as[Department]
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
+-------+---------+--------------------------+
|dept_id|dept_name|employee                  |
+-------+---------+--------------------------+
|10     |Sales    |[[1002,Rich], [1001,John]]|
+-------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Finally, save it as a json file:

```
dfDept .coalesce(1).write.json("department.json")
```

Comment: @Lux: No problems, happy to help :)